# "_reconfigure_port" fucntion in serialposix.py throws error while restarting the serial server. Pymodbus module is used

Tags: python-2.7, modbus, socat, pymodbus

I use Pymodbus module to start the synchronous serial server. I defined the port to be `'/dev/ttyUSB0'`.

In order to start the server, I make a virtual port using `socat`. Then I change the owner of the port from **`root`** to **`current user`**.

---

Below are the commands I use:

```
sudo socat pty,raw,echo=0,link=/dev/tUSB0 pty,raw,echo=0,link=/dev/ttyUSB1
sudo chown -c $USER /dev/ttyUSB*
```

I start and stop the server for the first time. But when I try to restart it, the server throws up the below error:

```
"File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pymodbus/server/sync.py", line 553, in StartSerialServer   File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pymodbus/server/sync.py", line 446, in
__init__   File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pymodbus/server/sync.py", line 462, in
_connect   File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/serial/serialutil.py", line 240, in __init__   File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/serial/serialposix.py", line 272, in open   File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/serial/serialposix.py", line 438, in _reconfigure_port termios.error: (22, 'Invalid argument')"
```

PS: I run the program on Ubuntu.

Comment: Did you try with `sudo chmod 777 /dev/ttyUSB*`?

Comment: @BenyaminJafari - I tried it. But it throws me the same error. any other option?